# Making a horizontal bar chart using flexbox - widths not working as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a horizontal bar chart by combining an `ul` with a `flexbox` grid. For some reason, my `li`s are not lining up with the correct lines on the chart based on their width(it's close but slightly off):

```css
section {
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 0;
}
  ul li {
      background:red;
      color:#fff;
      font-weight:700;
      margin-top:10px;
  }
      ul li:first-child {
          margin-top:0;
      }
div {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    flex: 1;
    z-index:-1;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    padding:inherit;
}
    div span {
        width: 1px;
        height: 100%;
        background: grey;
        position:relative;
    }
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
      <li style="width:100%;">Lorem</li>
      <li style="width:90%;">Ipsum</li>
      <li style="width:30%;">Dolor</li>
      <li style="width:60%;">Sit</li>
      <li style="width:70%;">Emet</li>
      <li style="width:10%;">Lorem</li>
      <li style="width:80%;">Ipsum</li>
      <li style="width:50%;">Dolor</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

The `li` with 100% width works fine, but the others don't line up correctly on the chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider backgroud to do this instead of a lot of code:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0 0 10px;
  overflow:auto;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
      transparent 0 calc(100% - 1px),grey calc(100% - 1px) 100%) 
      0 /calc(100%/10) 100%;
  border-left:1px solid grey;
}

ul li {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="width:100%;">Lorem</li>
  <li style="width:90%;">Ipsum</li>
  <li style="width:30%;">Dolor</li>
  <li style="width:60%;">Sit</li>
  <li style="width:70%;">Emet</li>
  <li style="width:10%;">Lorem</li>
  <li style="width:80%;">Ipsum</li>
  <li style="width:50%;">Dolor</li>
</ul>
```

It will be responsive and you can easily scale it to any number of lines:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  overflow:auto;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
      transparent 0 calc(100% - 1px),grey calc(100% - 1px) 100%) 
      0 /calc(100%/var(--n,10)) 100%;
  border-left:1px solid grey;
}

ul li {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="width:100%;">Lorem</li>
  <li style="width:30%;">Dolor</li>
  <li style="width:50%;">Dolor</li>
</ul>
<ul style="--n:15;width:400px">
  <li style="width:100%;">Lorem</li>
  <li style="width:30%;">Dolor</li>
  <li style="width:50%;">Dolor</li>
</ul>
<ul style="--n:20;width:400px">
  <li style="width:100%;">Lorem</li>
  <li style="width:30%;">Dolor</li>
  <li style="width:50%;">Dolor</li>
</ul>
```

Here is a different syntax:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  overflow:auto;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
      transparent 0 calc(100%/var(--n,10) - 1px)
      ,grey calc(100%/var(--n,10) - 1px) calc(100%/var(--n,10)));
  border-left:1px solid grey;
}

ul li {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="width:100%;">Lorem</li>
  <li style="width:30%;">Dolor</li>
  <li style="width:50%;">Dolor</li>
</ul>
<ul style="--n:15;width:400px">
  <li style="width:100%;">Lorem</li>
  <li style="width:30%;">Dolor</li>
  <li style="width:50%;">Dolor</li>
</ul>
<ul style="--n:20;width:400px">
  <li style="width:100%;">Lorem</li>
  <li style="width:30%;">Dolor</li>
  <li style="width:50%;">Dolor</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I do not understand. What caused that problem?. Which was in the question. @Temani Afif

Comment: @Pie he was missing one line in this code. You are supposed to have 11 lines in order to have 10 spaces which is easier with my code as I only have to repeat the gradient 10 times + a border at the left

Answer (score 2):

Add one more pair of span tags.

Currently, there are only nine (9) white space gaps between the 10% gray horizontal bars.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a simpler approach:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 5%;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 86vw;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 0.5%;
  height: 10vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.sb1 {
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

.sb2 {
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 70%;
}

.sb3 {
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

.sb4 {
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 30%;
}

.sb5 {
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar sb1"></div>
        <div class="sidebar sb2"></div>
        <div class="sidebar sb3"></div>
        <div class="sidebar sb4"></div>
        <div class="sidebar sb5"></div>
    </div>
```